# how to use int in scala messages file with play.api.i18n

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

As using hardcoded strings in scala(with play) is considered a sin. I have some hardcoded numbers in my code. So can i declare these numbers in the Messages file of play and then access them in project & convert them to Int/BigInteger whatever?

Comment: It make sense ONLY if these numbers are differet depending on selected language, otherwise as grotrian wrote application.conf is better idea to keep them

Answer (score 1):

for storing configuration data use application.conf which is located in ./conf directory and then use Play.current.configuration.getInt("some.property")  to retrieve it

Comment: Actually, during registration process of user. Some tables are to be created, in which, some hardcoded information(as default) is to be entered of relevant user. So, where should i keep this sort of string. In config or Messages file..?

Comment: I'd put them in config.